# jquery getJson and array

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have a problem with jQuery getJSON and displaing the result.

jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.getJSON("gsm.php",{getproducts:'495074, 495061, 495060'},function(response){
    jQuery.each(response, function() {
        jQuery('#item1').html(response.item1);
        jQuery('#item2').html(response.item2);
    });

});
});
```

gsm.php JSON response

```
[
{
    "item1": "test data 1",
    "item2": "test data 1a"
},
{
    "item1": "test data 2",
    "item2": "test data a"
}
]
```

I'm sorry but I couldn't solve my problem with other posts.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: ahh...what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("gsm.php", { getproducts: '495074, 495061, 495060' }, function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                $('#item1').html(value.item1);
                $('#item2').html(value.item2);
            });
        });

    });
```

You have missed this `function(key, value)` and use value to get data from json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
jQuery.each(response, function(index,value) {
        jQuery('#item1').html(value.item1);
        jQuery('#item2').html(value.item2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery.each(response, function() {
    jQuery('#item1').html(this.item1);
    jQuery('#item2').html(this.item2);
});
```